# Help Installing Dante Server From Source

Tags: server, compiling, proxy, make

Installing Dante from Source on Ubuntu

I was having problems with dante authentication therefore I am trying to install from source based on what this user has said:

https://serverfault.com/questions/611537/danted-socks-proxy-with-authentication

I performed `./configure`, `make,` and `make install`.

My log from installation is [here](http://pastebin.com/nacZTv8k).

I don't know where to go from here to start the service. I've tried "/etc/init.d/danted start" which is not working/missing. What step am I missing?

In my bin folder now are the following:

```
Makefile  Makefile.am  Makefile.in  socksify  socksify.in
```

This is my first time trying to install something not using apt-get. Please any advice would be appreciated. I assume I need to move files to a different directory and create a startup? But I'm not sure how to do this step by step.

Comment: Provide the download link.

Comment: https://www.inet.no/dante/files/dante-1.4.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

There is no script installed in `/etc/init.d/` or anywhere else.

Here is a list of the installed files:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/dante
/usr/share/doc/dante/BUGS
/usr/share/doc/dante/VERSION
/usr/share/doc/dante/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/dante/README
/usr/share/doc/dante/LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/dante/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/dante/README.ldap
/usr/share/doc/dante/INSTALL
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/SOCKS4.protocol
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/README.survey
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/Makefile.in
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/README.usage
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/socks.conf.5
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/README.socksify
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/rfc1929.txt
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/SOCKS4A.protocol
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/socksify.1
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/sockd.8
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/sockd.conf.5
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/rfc1928.txt
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/rfc1961.txt
/usr/share/doc/dante/doc/Makefile
/usr/local
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/socksify
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/include/socks.h
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/sbin/sockd
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/libsocks.a
/usr/local/lib/libdsocks.so
/usr/local/lib/libdsocks.la
/usr/local/lib/libsocks.la
/usr/local/lib/libsocks.so.0.1.1
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man5/socks.conf.5.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man5/sockd.conf.5.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/sockd.8.gz
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/socksify.1.gz
/usr/local/lib/libsocks.so
/usr/local/lib/libsocks.so.0
```

You have to write the start script yourself. Or you can start the socks server in a terminal, after you have created a configuration in `/etc/sockd.conf`. Read `man 5 socks.conf`.

```
/usr/local/sbin/sockd
```

Comment: But with default configure it should've built dante-server and dante-client, isn't it? Neither of those are in the list.